Is it true that the Shafi'i madhab allows forcing Non-Scriptural Disbelievers into Islam?
Why did classical scholars, particularly in the Shafi'i madhab, allow non-scriptural disbelievers to be compelled into Islam for the purpose of intercourse? As stated in Shu’ab al-Imān 3/12:
"وإنما ذكرت هذه المسألة رواية في الأمة الوثنية. فقد يجوز أن يكون فيها خاصة دون العبد. لأنه لا يمكن سيدها الاستمتاع بها مع وثنيتها، فيجبر بها على الإسلام، ليتمكن من الاستمتاع، كما يجبر الرجل امرأته الذمية على الغسل من الحيض لتهيأ." Source
I can share other Shafi'i scholars who argue the same thing, and if i recall correctly imam shafi'i himself too.
Additionally, how can some argue against forcing conversion while maintaining an inconsistent methodology?
JazakAllahu khairan.

As for the reason it is also stated in your quote itself, it is so that the owner can take benefit from the slave, in this case so that he can copulate with a female slave.  Your last question is unclear.

@UmH it isn't. I'm talking about whether the shafi'i madhab in particular, namely al halimi themselves (who is quoted above), permitted what I mentioned above. I made that as clear as i could when i created the title.

The linked answer covers the stance of the Shafi'is and of al-Halimi.

Salam and welcome to ISlamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

You hvae shared a statement from a book of al-Halimi a shafi'i scholar. Therein he holds the above mentioned position this doesn't reflect the majority view of his madhhab as shown in the answer of the question linked by @UmH.
